# Is a digital signature neccessary to properly install all INF files?

Tags: windows, driver, digital-signature, inf

I am trying to install a usb composite device I build on Windows 7(32bit & 64bit) and Windows8/8.1(32bit & 64bit).

The device composes of a Mass-storage and CDC Serial port device. I have provided an INF file to make Windows recognize the main composite device. Once that is recognized, I also provide INF for the CDC serial device. The mass-storage part functions without need of a INF file.

Now these INF files  uses drivers that normal default Windows drivers.(usbccgp.sys, usbser.sys) Even when using these "default" drivers and not changing anything in them, do I still need to get a digital signature to install this device? Is there anyway to write the INF so as to bypass this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signatures are enforced when installing the drivers in 64-bit Windows. The drivers won't work without being signed. And once you have a proper certificate (note that not every code signing certificate will work), you can sign both the driver and cat file (if used) with this certificate.

Comment: so I guess writing an INF file is considered as writing a driver? Even though I was just trying point to Windows the right "drivers" for the device.

Comment: @NazeKimi There's no way to check INF's signatures, but you do sign a .cat file if you use one.

Comment: Let us say I have gotten the INF file a signed catalog file. How do I then proceed to installing this INF file. Is using devcon [dp_add] command the right way in going about this?

Comment: @NazeKimi that's a totally different question. StackOverflow is not a forum but a question-answer site, where the question or tightly related questions are asked and answers are given. You are welcome to re-post your question as a new one (not as a comment) and somebody will answer you. I am not an expert in writing INF files, I just know a bit about how windows works with digital signatures.